# How can I iterate through two arrays at the same time without re-iterating through the parent loop?

Tags: php

How can I iterate through two arrays at the same time that have equal sizes ?

for example , first array `$a = array( 1,2,3,4,5);`
second array `$b = array(1,2,3,4,5);`

The result that I would like through iterating through both is having the looping process going through the same values to produce a result like

```
  1-1
  2-2
  3-3
  4-4
  5-5
```

I tried to do it this way below but it didn't work , it keeps going through the first loop again

```
foreach($a as $content) {
    foreach($b as $contentb){
        echo $a."-".$b."<br />"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Are these arrays indexed the same way? Then just iterate over the index... `for ($ii=...)`

Comment: possible duplicate: [php looping through multiple arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9171488/367456)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use a normal `for` loop instead of a `foreach`, so that you get an explicit loop counter:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($content)-1; $i++) {
  echo $content[$i].'-'.$contentb[$i];
}
```

If you want to use string based indexed arrays, and know that the string indexes are equal between arrays, you can stick with the `foreach` construct

```
foreach($content as $key=>$item) {
  echo $item.'-'.$contentb[$key];
}
```

Comment: won't work if he starts using arrays with string based indexes!

Comment: otherwise that's what i would have used too

Comment: @ITroubs added case for string based indexes, even though the example data in the question do not specify any need for this.

Comment: Should be for($i=0; $i<count($content); $i++) or for($i=0; $i<=count($content)-1; $i++)

Comment: This doesn't work for arrays with different set of keys

Comment: @Danon second example works assuming arrays share length and element order.

Answer (score 24):

Not the most efficient, but a demonstration of SPL's multipleIterator

```
$mi = new MultipleIterator();
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($a));
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($b));

$newArray = array();
foreach ( $mi as $value ) {
    list($value1, $value2) = $value;
    echo $value1 , '-' , $value2 , PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: And since PHP 5.5 (maybe sooner?) you can even do `foreach ($mi as [$value1, $value2])`

Comment: I like the object oriented approach

Comment: I didn't know this iterator and it's resolve my problem. Thank you, i approve your solution rather than one selected

Answer (score 4):

If they're the same size, just do this:

```
foreach($a as $key => $content){
   $contentb = $b[$key];
   echo($content."-".$contentb."<br />");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for arrays with different set of keys.